# NameError: name 'KEYDOWN' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, nameerror

I am new to programming with PyGame and I've made this code:

```py
import sys, pygame
pygame.init()
size = width, height = 800, 600
speed = [2, 2]
black = 1, 1, 1
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
ball = pygame.image.load("ball.bmp")
ballrect = ball.get_rect()
player1 = pygame.image.load("player1.png")
player1rect = player1.get_rect()
mod_x = mod_y = 0
while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_W:
                movex = 2
            if event.key == K_S:
                movex = -2
    ballrect = ballrect.move(speed)
    if ballrect.left < 0 or ballrect.right > width:
        speed[0] = -speed[0]
    if ballrect.top < 0 or ballrect.bottom > height:
        speed[1] = -speed[1]
    screen.fill(black)
    screen.blit(ball, ballrect)
    screen.blit(player1, player1rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

But when I execute my code, I get this error:

```sh
File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Pong\pong.py", line 22, in <module>
    elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
NameError: name 'KEYDOWN' is not defined
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please help me. I need it so much, I need an answer quick.

Comment: why write pygame.QUIT, when you write KEYDOWN?

Answer (score 2):

`KEYDOWN` isn't defined in your code.  You can add this to the beginning:

```
from pygame.locals import *
```

Or you can do this:

```
elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this command while using pygame library

```
...
elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN
...
```

Answer (score 0):

just change this piece, then it should work :)

elif event.type == KEYDOWN:   CHANGE TO: elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: