# Keydown function not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have just downloaded pygame 1.9.2  for python 3.3 and the `keydown` function is not working. The IDLE shell keeps telling me the same error:

```
NameError: name 'KEYDOWN' is not defined
```

How do I solve this problem? I am kinda new to programming so could you please explain this to me.

Comment: You can add this to the beginning:

from pygame.locals import *

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NameError: name 'KEYDOWN' is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17556426/nameerror-name-keydown-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE: Sorry for deleting my previous answer but Stack Overflow just randomly posted my answer before I was done.**

Well, there could be several things wrong. You could be using `pygame.key.keydown()`, which is wrong, and you should be using `pygame.key.get_pressed()`.
But what I suspect is wrong with your code is that you're not using `pygame.KEYDOWN` properly.

If you're trying to do something while a key is being held down, use `pygame.key.get_pressed()`, and do something like this:

```
key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if key[pygame.K_WHATEVER_KEY_YOU_WANT]:
    # do code
```

and just repeat that for every key you want to check.

If you're just trying to check if a key is being pressed, use `pygame.KEYDOWN` with an if statement, then check if the key you want is being pressed in a nested if statement **under** the first if statement. Like so:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_WHATEVER_KEY_YOU_WANT:
        #do code
```

I'm assuming you have an event variable your using to iterate over `pygame.event.get()` function that 'gets' events. If not then here is the code **above** in a game/window loop:

```
running = True  # variable to control while loop

while running:  # while the variable running is equal to true
    for event in pygame.event.get():  # use the variable 'event' to iterate over user events
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # test if the user is trying to close the window
            running = False  # break the loop if the user is trying to close the window
            pygame.quit()  # de-initialize pygame module
            quit()  # quit() the IDE shell

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_WHATEVER_KEY_YOU_WANT:
               #do code
```

This is basically how you use `pygame.KEYDOWN`. It's probably not the only way however. I recommend (since you're new to programming) to read the [pygame docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) on their official website for more info about checking key input in pygame. And read some of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25494726/how-to-use-pygame-keydown) to this question.